# android mkdirs in SD card return false.help me, it spends me 3days

Tags: android, mkdirs

I want to create a folder in SD card ,and i already add the permission

```
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in manifest file.below is my code,but mkdirs return false! Can you help me!

```
File exportDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "happydiarybackup");
        if (!exportDir.exists()) {
            boolean a = exportDir.mkdirs();
            Log.d("mkdir ",exportDir.getAbsolutePath() + " make "+ a);
        }
```

Comment: What log messages were generated?

Comment: now it is working.I just put the permission at the first of the manifest file,I don`t know why ,but it`s worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It might help you.

```
String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/happydiarybackup/";
try
{
    File dir = new File(fullPath);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
      dir.mkdirs();
    }
}
 catch (Exception e) {
   Log.e("App", "Exception" + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thank you !now it is working.I just put the permission at the first of the manifest file,I don`t know why ,but it`s worked!

Answer (score 1):

1.Check your compileSdkVersion
2.[Android: mkdirs()/mkdir() on external storage returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212559/android-mkdir-returns-false).
Make sure your put the permission tag in.